# Why is my function only returning one item from a list?

Tags: python

I'm learning python to improve my skills. I am building a web app to keep track of freelancers I work with. I am following a tutorial but making it on my own.

Here is the code:

```
freelancers = ["juan", "andre"] #original list


def get_freelancer_titlecase(): # makes freelancers TitleCased
    freelancers_in_titlecase = []#empty dict
    for freelancer in freelancers:
        freelancers_in_titlecase = freelancer.title()
        return freelancers_in_titlecase

def print_freelancers_in_titlecase():#print freelancers in TitleCase
    print_freelancers_in_titlecase = get_freelancer_titlecase()
    print(print_freelancers_in_titlecase)

freelancer_list = get_freelancer_titlecase() # Place the function inside a variable
print(freelancer_list)# here is my problem, this returns only the first entry "Juan", in title case but stops there.

print(freelancers)# this is a check to see the items on the list and they are ["juan", "andre"]
```

Why is `print(freelancer_list)` only returning one item?
I need to be able to call the list and get all freelancers in title case. Later it should be a dictionary to hold an ID also and of course input for each freelancer.

This is my first question, so thank you in advance.

Comment: Your 'empty dict' isn't a dict (talking about `freelancers_in_titlecase = []#empty dict`), it is a list, which you overwrite in `freelancers_in_titlecase = freelancer.title()`. As a result, you're not returning a list in `def get_freelancer_titlecase()`, you're returning 1 variable.

Comment: `return` instantly leaves the function scope, that's why you only get one item back. To fix this either create a list and return that after iterating with the for-loop or use generator expressions and yield.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning from function  `get_freelancer_titlecase(`) immediately after getting first element.

You need to store to list  `freelancers_in_titlecase` using `append` and return at the end outside `for` loop.

```
freelancers = ["juan", "andre"] #original list

def get_freelancer_titlecase(): # makes freelancers TitleCased
    freelancers_in_titlecase = []
    for freelancer in freelancers:
        freelancers_in_titlecase.append(freelancer.title())
    return freelancers_in_titlecase

def print_freelancers_in_titlecase():#print freelancers in TitleCase
    print_freelancers_in_titlecase = get_freelancer_titlecase()
    print(print_freelancers_in_titlecase)

freelancer_list = get_freelancer_titlecase() # Place the function inside a variable

print(freelancer_list)  # ['Juan', 'Andre']
print(freelancers)  # ['juan', 'andre'] 

print_freelancers_in_titlecase()  # This function prints titlecased list.
```

Comment: I was expecting having to wait for help. This is the Best Forum Ever

Comment: Thank you, i have understood

Comment: @juanIturbe We have a convention of accepting answers. Accept any answer that you find helpful by pressing tick mark on left. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

In this function:

```
def get_freelancer_titlecase(): # makes freelancers TitleCased
    freelancers_in_titlecase = []#empty dict
    for freelancer in freelancers:
        freelancers_in_titlecase = freelancer.title()
        return freelancers_in_titlecase
```

You should append to "freelancers_in_titlecase", so the code should be changed to:

```
def get_freelancer_titlecase(): # makes freelancers TitleCased
    freelancers_in_titlecase = []#empty list
    for freelancer in freelancers:
        freelancers_in_titlecase.append(freelancer.title())
    return freelancers_in_titlecase
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your `get_freelancer_titlecase()` function.

```
def get_freelancer_titlecase(): # makes freelancers TitleCased
    freelancers_in_titlecase = []#empty dict
    for freelancer in freelancers:
        freelancers_in_titlecase = freelancer.title()
        return freelancers_in_titlecase
```

This function does the following:

1. Creates an empty list (not a dict) named `freelancers_in_titlecase`
2. Loops through the items in the `freelancers` list.
3. *Replaces* the empty list `freelancers_in_titlecase` with the title case of the first freelancer.
4. Returns that value (before the loop finishes).

Try this instead.

```
def get_freelancer_titlecase(): # makes freelancers TitleCased
    freelancers_in_titlecase = [] #empty list
    for freelancer in freelancers:
        freelancers_in_titlecase.append(freelancer.title())
    return freelancers_in_titlecase
```

That will *add* each freelancer's title case to the list, and only return the list once the loop is finished.

If you want to change that to return a `dict` with the original name as a key and the title case as a value, you can do it like this:

```
def get_freelancer_titlecase(): # makes freelancers TitleCased
    freelancers_in_titlecase = {} # empty dict
    for freelancer in freelancers:
        freelancers_in_titlecase[freelancer] = freelancer.title()
    return freelancers_in_titlecase
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning `freelancers_in_titlecase` just after the first loop, and moreover you are overriding the variable. So you should bring `return` outside the `for loop` and `append` the variable instead of replacing them:

```
def get_freelancer_titlecase(): # makes freelancers TitleCased
    freelancers_in_titlecase = []#it is actually a list
    for freelancer in freelancers:
        freelancers_in_titlecase.append(freelancer.title())
    return freelancers_in_titlecase
```

You could think to rewrite this function with List Comprehensions:

```
def get_freelancer_titlecase():
    freelancers_in_titlecase = [freelancer.title() for freelancer in freelancers]
    return freelancers_in_titlecase
```